# Vtiger. Проблема с новой версией MySql

Tags: php, vtiger-api

Всем привет.

Возникла проблема, была версия MySql 5.5, но я обновил к MySql 5.6 и из-за этого возникли проблемы с созданием проектов и т.п.

Пример ошибки, которая возвращается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как у вас соединение с б.д происходит?

Comment: Другие модуля работают. Проблема заключается в одном модуле.
я с помощью Curl, отправляю массив в vtiger, и получаю данный ответ.

Comment: В этой версии есть нововведения, например если в SELECT есть поля, которых нет в GROUP BY, это приводит к фатальной ошибке. То что вам показывается, ничего не сообщает. Добавьте вывод ошибочного запроса, каким способом я не скажу. Я бы поковырялся на этот счет в документации, затем посмотрел сырцы. В крайнем случае - включить в мускуле general log и копаться уже в нем.